# XSLT copy elements from second XML if not exist in the first XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following XMLs:

car.xml:

```
<car ref-id="parts.xml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <color>red</color>
  <tire>michelin</tire>
  <engines>
    <engine>
      <model>Z</model>
    </engine>
  </engines>
  <hifi>pioneer</hifi>
</car>
```

parts.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<parts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <engines>
    <engine>
      <model>X</model>
    </engine>
    <engine>
      <model>Y</model>
    </engine>
  </engines>
  <tire>goodyear</tire>
  <color>black</color>
  <airbag>true</airbag>
</parts>
```

I'd like to merge parts.xml with car.xml, but want to copy only those nodes from parts.xml (regardless of their value) which doesn't exist in car.xml.

E.g, I'd need the following output:

```
<car xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <color>red</color>
  <tire>michelin</tire>
  <engines>
    <engine>
      <model>Z</model>
    </engine>
  </engines>  
  <hifi>pioneer</hifi>
  <airbag>true</airbag>
</car>
```

I'm stuck at the following transformation which merges all the elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:variable name="loc">
        <xsl:value-of select="car/@ref-id" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="car">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node() | document($loc)/parts/*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a rather awkward arrangement to have, and the solution - at least in XSLT 1.0 - is no less awkward:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/car">
    <xsl:variable name="local-names">
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <name><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></name>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="document(@ref-id)/parts/*[not(name()=exsl:node-set($local-names)/name)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If I alter `<engines>` in car.xml to `<engines override="true">` and want to copy `<engines>` from part.txt only if `override="false"`,
how to do that? I exteded local names with `<attr><xsl:value-of select="@override"/></attr>` but the additional condition on copy-of
`exsl:node-set($local-names)/attr='false'` doesn't work.

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. Either add this to your question (with a full code example)  or post a new one. --- BTW, if you have  control over the input XML, consider using an attribute (name or id) to identify the parts, instead of element names.

Comment: I created a follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30707331/4020050 . Would be great if you could help me again to figure out this issue.