# XSLT copy elements from second XML if an attribute is set in the first XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following input XMLs:
car.xml:

```
<car ref-id="parts.xml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <color>red</color>
  <tire>michelin</tire>
  <engines override="false">
    <engine>
      <model>Z</model>
    </engine>
  </engines>
  <hifi>pioneer</hifi>
</car>
```

parts.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<parts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <engines>
    <engine>
      <model>X</model>
    </engine>
    <engine>
      <model>Y</model>
    </engine>
  </engines>
  <tire>goodyear</tire>
  <color>black</color>
  <airbag>true</airbag>
</parts>
```

I'd like to merge parts.xml with car.xml, but want to copy only those nodes from parts.xml (regardless of their value) which:

- A, doesn't exist in car.xml
- B, exists in car xml, but the element's
  "override" attribute is set to false.

[Michael-hor257k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3016153/michael-hor257k) provided a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30697657/xslt-copy-elements-from-second-xml-if-not-exist-in-the-first-xml) to A, but I'm stuck implementing B.

Then XSLT looks like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="loc">
    <xsl:value-of select="car/@ref-id" />
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/car">
    <xsl:variable name="local-names">
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <name>
                <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
            </name>
            <attr>
                <xsl:value-of select="@override" />
            </attr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
        <xsl:copy-of
            select="document($loc)/parts/*[not(name()=exsl:node-set($local-names)/name)] or 
                exsl:node-set($local-names)/attr='false'"/> 
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

I tried to add

```
<attr>
  <xsl:value-of select="@override" />
</attr>
```

and 
`or exsl:node-set($local-names)/attr='false'` to the XSLT but no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change line #10 from:

```
<xsl:for-each select="*">
```

to:

```
<xsl:for-each select="*[not(@override='false')]">
```

You didn't post the expected result, so I am not sure it will be to your liking. This could prove much more complicated than it seems, if you need to merge nodes at different levels.

Comment: Great, thank you again! I'm doing the merging in a second pass, only for the <engine> elements on the first level

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
        <attr>
            <xsl:value-of select="@override" />
        </attr>
```

To:

```
        <attr>
            <xsl:value-of select="engines/@override" />
        </attr>
```